# htaccess and cookies issue for multilingual site

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

There is a conflict between my htaccess file and my php code.

This is a part of my htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^(it|fr)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?lang=en [L,QSA]
```

And now my php code in the header of all pages :

```
if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
  $lang = $_GET['lang'];
  $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
  setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
  $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
  $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else {
  $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'],0,2);
}
```

The problème now is that i can't use this :

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] = 'fr'){
  header('Location: https://mysite.tv/fr/');
}
```

There is a "redirection loop".

I want a user in 'fr' or 'it' to be redirect to /fr/ or /it/
But (very important) i want also that a user /fr/ or /it/ could change his default directory.
(for example a french user want to visit my website in english language) and keep this information in cookie.

Any idea ?

Comment: Is it misprint at if ($_SERVER[...]='fr') or real code? If second then it will be true always, because you are using assignment instead of comparison.

Comment: it is no misprint, but this is not the most important issue